# React - Promise won't add response data to array through useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, es6-promise

I'm writing app for store youtube links inside with ability to play, add to favorites, etc.

I can add videos one per one and everything works fine, every item pushed to list is added on end of my list as i wanted. But i have a problem in moment of trying assing multiple youtube links to my main-app-state for store array with my own type youtube-movie-object. But when i'm doing it in a loop, my list doesn't getting updated.

After long time of looking what wrong is going on i think got it. It's something with assinging response to state.

I'm using axios to fetch data from YouTubeAPI, and i have array of youtube links i'm looping.

```
const Component = () => {
  ...
    const [youtubeList, setYoutubeList] = useState([]);
  ...
    const toggleSetYoutubeListAsDefault = () => {
      YoutubeLinks.forEach(link => { //i'm going through each link
         let data = FetchVideoData(link); 
         //data.promise = Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>
         data.promise.then(response => DescribedVideo.MakeYoutubeTypeObject(response.data.items[0]))
         .then(newResponse => {
           setYoutubeList( youtubeList => [...youtubeList, newResponse])
           console.log(youtubeList) // returns: [] (empty array every iteration, should contains newResponse objects)
           console.log(newResponse) // return: {expected object with correct data}
         })
      })
    };
```

How can i build it to achive expected result, mean assign response to my state?
I tried many ways, googled for solution but ain't find anything working 4 me :/

Maybe someone would be that nice to help me with that?
**Thanks in advance :-)**

Comment: State updates are not synchronous. React batches them for performance. This is well covered in the docs. Also, your side effects should be in a useEffect hook, which is also well covered.

Comment: @JaredSmith it depends on if toggleSetYoutubeListAsDefault is an effect or an event callback (for some kind of dom event). IIRC calling the setter in an event callback won't get batched, and the component will rerender once for every call to the setter. OP, are you using this function as a useEffect or as an event callback?

Comment: thanks for response! I'm (think)unfortunetly using this function as event callback.
shoud i use useEffect in this case?

Comment: If it should be called when a button is pressed / other user input, an event callback is probably right. useEffect would be good if it should be called every time some other state variable or prop changes.

Comment: Jared Smith wrote about state updates are not synchronous. So how can I take response outside Promise and for example assign it to new variable?

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```js
setYoutubeList( youtubeList => [...youtubeList, newResponse])
console.log(youtubeList) // returns: [] (empty array every iteration, should contains newResponse objects)
```

The `console.log(youtubeList)` shows an empty array because useState state is immutable. When you got the `youtubeList` array from useState, that variable points to an array object that won't change. The new array is only accessible the next time the component renders, which should be soon after calling the setter. Also I see you passed a function to the useState setter, which is very good because otherwise every call to the setter would be using that old youtubeList array object, not the latest updated one.

I am not sure how you can fix your problem, but I know the `console.log(youtubeList)` showing an empty array is not a problem at all. Try `console.log(youtubeList)` outside the callback, right after your useState call, to see what the state is every time the component rerenders, and see if it gets updated correctly. This should be printing several times for every time `toggleSetYoutubeListAsDefault` is called.

You might also try a setter like this:

```js
setYoutubeList( currentYoutubeList => {
  console.log(currentYoutubeList)
  return [...currentYoutubeList, newResponse]
})
```

To see if any of the setter updates are incorporated.

Comment: when im ``console.log(youtubeList)`` outside callback effect is the same, my state stays empty

Comment: Does this new print statement get called several times, all of them empty array? This shouldn't be the problem, but you could try renaming the arrow function parameter so it doesn't have the same name as the state: `setYoutubeList( currentYoutubeList => [...currentYoutubeList, newResponse])`

Comment: i tried renaming it, without expected result :/  Mean state array is still empty. I read in one thear to make handler function for that callback and then assign variable to state, but still doesnt work :/

Comment: Try to see if you can recreate the bug in a codepen/codesandbox/etc. You can mock functions like MakeYoutubeTypeObject

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-haze-qumq9?file=/src/components/SiteNavbar.js

I cut some of not important code and dont share the whole app

Comment: There are import errors in that link currently: "../hooks/ListProvider" not found

Answer (score 0):

When doing this:

```
setYoutubeList( currentYoutubeList => {
  console.log(currentYoutubeList)
  return [...currentYoutubeList, newResponse]
})
```

It's loggin:

```
 [{…}]
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  ....
 so it is what we expected
```

but when i'm console.log outside the setYoutubeList and .then scope my list ist still empty.

however i tried to make it in not-react way. I make new `var youtubeObject = []` and in last .then i tried

```
const toggleSetYoutubeListAsDefault = () => {
      var youtubeObjects = []
      YoutubeLinks.forEach(link => { //i'm going through each link
         let data = FetchVideoData(link); 
         data.promise.then(response => DescribedVideo.MakeYoutubeTypeObject(response.data.items[0]))
         .then(newResponse => youtubeObjects.push(newResponse))
      })
    console.log(youtubeObjects) // return [] (like empty) but after expand in browser console it contains items. 
     //but when tring to
     youtubeObjects.forEach(...) //error = youtubeObjects are not iterabble
    };
```

Can somebody try to explain me why its so difficult to assign response out of Promise? :D